# Numpy apply function in pairs of rows and accumulate results

Tags: python, function, numpy, list-comprehension

I want to do something simple yet I have not found a smart way to do so.

Assuming that I have a `numpy` array with 3 rows like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.514, 0.966, 0.443, 0.95 , 0.524, 0.423, 0.75 , 0.463, 0.721, 0.089],
              [0.929, 0.014, 0.275, 0.521, 0.739, 0.612, 0.366, 0.469, 0.575, 0.533],
              [0.235, 0.084, 0.994, 0.713, 0.421, 0.851, 0.66 , 0.231, 0.699, 0.216]])
```

I want to apply the following function ***on each pairs of rows and accumulate the results*** ***i.e (row0 with row1) -> (output of previous step with row 3) and so on***:

```
def myfunc(x,y):
    return x**2 + y**2 - x*y
```

Manually this would look something like:

```
tmp1 = myfunc(a[0],a[1])
results = myfunc(tmp1,a[2])
```

Now, I want to generalze this in a smart way for a general `N (N = a.shape[0])`.

I have tried list comprehension-based approaches but I cannot generalize it for any N.

---

**Edit 1:**

Example for N=4:

```
tmp1 = myfunc(a[0],a[1])
tmp2 = myfunc(tmp1,a[2])
results = myfunc(tmp2,a[3])
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop.  Or use the `functools.reduce` function (py3).  `numpy` `ufunc` also have a `reduce` method.

Comment: Hey. A for loop would be ok but I have tried to use a for loop and again I do not find a way to generalize it.

Comment: Clarify what you want with higher N, 4 or 5 etc.

Comment: See edit 1 for N=4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a naive way of solving it using a `for` loop, over the first dimension (i.e. axis-0):

```
# your custom function; slightly rewritten because
# * based multiplication is faster than `pow()`
In [93]: def myfunc(x,y):
    ...:     return x*x + y*y - x*y


# to be replenished after each iteration
In [95]: res = a[0]

# go over rows and compute the results using `myfunc()`
In [96]: for i in range(a.shape[0]-1):
    ...:    curr_step_res = myfunc(res, a[i+1])
    ...:    res = curr_step_res[:]


# final result
In [97]: res
Out[97]: 
array([0.32468859, 0.775874  , 0.861402  , 0.4852772 , 0.18264236,
       0.56028635, 0.33515591, 0.05036018, 0.37391415, 0.05364418])
```

---

#### sanity check with manual calls

```
In [99]: tmp1 = myfunc(a[0],a[1])
In [100]: results = myfunc(tmp1,a[2])

In [101]: np.allclose(results, res)
Out[101]: True
```

---

#### results for your case with N=4

```
# sample array to work with
In [102]: a = np.random.random_sample((4, 6))

# to be replenished after each iteration
In [103]: res = a[0]

In [104]: for i in range(a.shape[0]-1):
     ...:    curr_step_res = myfunc(res, a[i+1])
     ...:    res = curr_step_res[:]

In [105]: res
Out[105]: 
array([0.51971283, 0.61377465, 0.0838452 , 0.2201938 , 0.54028219,
       0.19318569])

# compute using manual calls
In [106]: tmp1 = myfunc(a[0],a[1])
     ...: tmp2 = myfunc(tmp1,a[2])
     ...: results = myfunc(tmp2,a[3])

# sanity check for equality of both results
In [107]: np.allclose(results, res)
Out[107]: True
```

P.S. this should generalize to any `N`, where `N = arr.shape[0]`. Also, note that there is no straightforward way to parallelize this because the compute is sequential.

Comment: that's exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

A simplified version of your function, and an `a` that should highlight the action:

```
In [344]: def myfunc(x,y): 
     ...:     return 2*x + y 
     ...: a = np.eye(5)                                                              
In [345]: a                                                                          
Out[345]: 
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
In [346]: res = myfunc(a[0],a[1])                                                    
In [347]: res                                                                        
Out[347]: array([2., 1., 0., 0., 0.])
In [348]: for i in a[2:]: 
     ...:     res = myfunc(res,i) 
     ...:                                                                            
In [349]: res                                                                        
Out[349]: array([16.,  8.,  4.,  2.,  1.])
```

Python has a `reduce` function to repeatedly apply a function to a list.  In Py3 this is in `functools`:

```
In [355]: functools.reduce(myfunc, a)                                                
Out[355]: array([16.,  8.,  4.,  2.,  1.])
```

Or starting with a zero `res`, and apply to the whole array:

```
In [357]: res = np.zeros(a.shape[1])                                                 
In [358]: for i in a: 
     ...:     res = myfunc(res,i) 
     ...:                                                                            
In [359]: res                                                                        
Out[359]: array([16.,  8.,  4.,  2.,  1.])
```

To save intermediate results:

```
In [361]: res = [np.zeros(a.shape[1])] 
     ...: for i in a: 
     ...:     temp = myfunc(res[-1],i) 
     ...:     res.append(temp)                                                                            
In [362]: res                                                                        
Out[362]: 
[array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
 array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
 array([2., 1., 0., 0., 0.]),
 array([4., 2., 1., 0., 0.]),
 array([8., 4., 2., 1., 0.]),
 array([16.,  8.,  4.,  2.,  1.])]
```

This is the concept of `accumulate`.  `numpy` `ufunc` have both `reduce` and `accumulate`, and will be faster, if `myfunc` can be written with them.  But that doesn't work in a general case.

```
In [363]: np.add.accumulate(a,axis=0)                                                
Out[363]: 
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```